# how to use image in background more efficiently?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, render

I created application which has a background image.
I tested this application with **Profile GPU Rendering** and found out app works smoothly without an image in the background. Even when the size of my image is less than 10kb it takes time to execute display list as you can see in image which shows long red bars which represents *execute display list operation*.
 [Screen shot of my app with Profile GPU Rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc1vV.png)

How can I use image in my app's background with less performance hit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide follow this. It will increase performance. It will really help when u load large number of images as well